# Fltk Window wait

Tags: c++, user-interface, fltk

C++ fltk: I have a window with an in_box and an out_box, how do I make it so that the user can type into the in_box hit enter, then proceed with the rest of the event. Right now the window just shows up and goes away.

```
Window w(Point(100,100),200,200, "Category Sales");
In_box cat_in(Point(75,75),100,20,"Category:");
Out_box cat_out(Point(75,115),100,20,"Sales:");
w.attach(cat_in);
w.attach(enter);
category = cat_in.get_string();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly if this will fix your problem, but to keep the window open, return Fl::run().

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen In_box and Out_box before, so I will assume those are your own classes or structures...
As pointed before - the easiest way to start the FLTK event loop is to use Fl::run() or (FLTK2) fltk::run().

So, here your code should look something like (FLTK2):

```
#include <fltk/Window.h>
#include <fltk/Widget.h>
#include <fltk/run.h>

using namespace fltk;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  // your code begins
  Window w(Point(100,100),200,200, "Category Sales");
  In_box cat_in(Point(75,75),100,20,"Category:");
  Out_box cat_out(Point(75,115),100,20,"Sales:");
  w.attach(cat_in);
  w.attach(enter);
  category = cat_in.get_string();
  // your code ends

  w->end();
  w->show(argc, argv);
  return run(); // this line is the most important, here we start the FLTK event-loop
}
```